# Is there a way to install homebrew without git?

Tags: homebrew

For reasons pertaining to storage and git, installing homebrew comes with the issue of:

```
Error: 
  homebrew-core is a shallow clone.
  homebrew-cask is a shallow clone.
To `brew update`, first run:
  git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow
  git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask fetch --unshallow
These commands may take a few minutes to run due to the large size of the repositories.
This restriction has been made on GitHub's request because updating shallow
clones is an extremely expensive operation due to the tree layout and traffic of
Homebrew/homebrew-core and Homebrew/homebrew-cask. We don't do this for you
automatically to avoid repeatedly performing an expensive unshallow operation in
CI systems (which should instead be fixed to not use shallow clones). Sorry for
the inconvenience!
```

It explicitly states what to do next, but I've found that running those git commands is a pretty terrible experience with slow internet (or just in general).  The absolute best solution to such an issue would be if there were torrents which contained the entire project folder including git.  Barring that, a simple download would be nice.  Really, anything but git is in scope of this question.

To reiterate the issues with using git:

- requires git
- opaque UX by default (tends to hang without any updates for long periods of time)
- not great for slow connections
- wrong tool for a situation that only involves downloading files

**Is there an alternative path to Homebrew that doesn't incorporate git?**

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
Check the skip-tap cloning section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can use the [skip tap cloning](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#skip-tap-cloning-beta) feature of Homebrew.   Note that this is, for now, a beta feature:

> **Skip Tap Cloning (beta)**
>
> You can instruct Homebrew to skip cloning the
> Homebrew/homebrew-core tap during installation by setting the beta
> HOMEBREW_INSTALL_FROM_API environment variable with the following:
>
> ```
> export HOMEBREW_INSTALL_FROM_API=1
> /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
> ```
>
> This will make Homebrew install formulae and casks from the
> homebrew/core and homebrew/cask taps using Homebrew’s API instead of
> local checkouts of these repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with OP 100%.

Homebrew should simply provide a downloadable file.  Especially since GitHub has implemented a very unfriendly interface and the default shell in MacOS Ventura is now zsh which Homebrew specifically states will not work with their provided Terminal install command.

If you make it so difficult to install your software, then don't be surprised that fewer people use it.

Edit:  I suppose they just don't really care, but I spent a few hours trying to get Homebrew up to date tonight because of GitHub.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).